# Pegar erros gerados no javaScript e exibir em uma div

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma `div` chamada `log` e gostaria de capturar tudo o que é gerado no console, logo abaixo eu gero um erro de index a indefinido `a += 8;`. O problema está que ele só captura o primeiro erro.

- Como faço pra mostrar todos erros gerados ao abrir a página?
- E como faço pra mostrar **qualquer** erro que possa vir a ser gerado
  durante a execução do código?

```js
var log = document.getElementById('log');

window.onerror = function(message, url, lineNumber) {  
  log.innerHTML += lineNumber + ":<br/>" + message + "<br/>In: " + url;
};

a += 8; //Index indefinido;
b += 5; //Index indefinido;
//funcaoindefinida(); //Função indefinida;
//var var = 0; //Palavra reservada;
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

Tentei trabalhar com `try...catch(e)` mas também só pega o primeiro erro gerado no código

```js
var log = document.getElementById('log');
try{
  a += 8; //Index indefinido;
  b += 5; //Index indefinido;
  //funcaoindefinida(); //Função indefinida;
  //var var = 0; //Palavra reservada;
}
catch(e){
  log.innerHTML += e.message;
}
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Mas onde você pega o primeiro erro no console? Me parece que o problema é aí.

Comment: Então @bigwn, acreditava que o `window.onerror` funcionava dessa forma, sempre que houvesse algum erro no `window`, a variável `log` receberia mais esse erro.

Comment: É o oposto, o `catch` vai prevenir o erro. Vou sair, se ninguém responder, eu testo e tento responder.

Comment: olha, fiz um teste aqui e deu certo: http://jsfiddle.net/a0Lx0cjy/2/

Comment: @TobyMosque a questão é que só pega o primeiro erro. No seu caso "funcionou" porquê o evento `click` só faz gerar `1` erro, então ele pega sem problemas. Marcelo, acredito não ser fácil fazer isso (pra não dizer impossível sem ter certeza), pois quando um erro de execução acontece o _script_ é interrompido veja nesse [JSFiddler do Toby que eu modifiquei](http://jsfiddle.net/a0Lx0cjy/3/)

Comment: Quando acontece uma `exception` ele para a execução, é por isso que você só consegue recuperar o primeiro error.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio qual o contexto onde essa captura de erros ocorre? Me parece que utilizar uma IDE com verificação de erros (Netbeans por exemplo) resolveria o problema

Comment: Éé não @sanção, seriam erros gerados em tempo de execução, e não de sintaxe, como index em um array não definido